# XQuery to Order elements(xi:include) in an xml file

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

Do any one know how to order elements in XML file. I have a course XML file and my course XML file has 5 units which are referenced as `xi:include`.

Each unit in turn has a `unitsequencenumber` element. I need to have my course XML returned with unit references ordered based on `unitsequencenumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by`:

```
for $e in doc('filename.xml')/unit
order by $e/unitsequencenumber
return $e
```